# Using PHP to FTP file from local xampp server to online free server. can it be done?

Tags: php, file, ftp, xampp

I am trying to do this as part of a project for college. Basically I have created a file In php within a script. This PHP script is running Locally on my xampp server. My file is also located on the xampp server. What I want to do Is FTP this file, using PHP and possibly Filezilla to an online free hosting server I have setup.Is this possible to do? Thanks for any Info you can give me on this in advance :)

Comment: And you have tried what...?  Maybe something with http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php ?

Comment: ha ha cheers dude! at least now I know its possible and im not wasting my time.

Comment: @j0k kinda detracts not being able to simply write 'Yes.' don't it :)  OP, you will have better luck with getting answers if you show you tried to answer the question yourself first: Maybe give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - Just trying to be constructive - best of luck with your studies.

Comment: cheers for the advice

Comment: @ficuscr for this kind of question, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is "how do I deploy my PHP script to a free hosting server."

In order to do this, you need to first sign up for a hosting server - let's assume you went with Amazon EC2 for simplicity. It's not free, but it's cheap and easy to set up (go with a micro instance).

Once you sign up, you will obtain SSH access to the box. Afterwards, you can install Apache/PHP on your new box (ex. via XAMPP). An appropriate SSH client (ex. Tunnelier if you're on Windows) will allow you to transfer files over to the EC2 box via a built-in SFTP client.

If you don't want to use EC2, consider Googling for "PHP hosting" - you might be able to find a free one; make sure it offers FTP access, and you're golden.

Comment: thanks, but yeah im just trying to send a .csv file from my xampp server (local) . to a free hosted server using a php script running on the xampp server. Its just a small college project so I wasn't going to bother spending money this time. thanks for the advice

Comment: look im sure ill have some more questions about this topic. next time ill include code etc. I did research to see whether this could be done and couldnt find an answer anywhere. hence  I had to ask the question here.